# How do you see the code for locked google forms?

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, virtual-machine, google-forms, chromebook

My friend is making an escape room with respond validation and locked mode. You can see the answer for respond validation:
[1]: https://youtu.be/400kENpsAHc

When I tried this with a Chromebook that had been locked, I couldn't use control U or inspect, it just simply doesn't let me.

Is there anyway for me to get the source code?
Ideas: VM (With a Chromebook and may be able to bypass the lock), extension (A way for me to see it). Or is there any other ways for me to get the answers, thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access the codes.
because the Chromebook will cut off all other web pages from loading, and i don't think an extension can access the google forms when it is on locked mode.
In my opinion, the idea to access the code while it's in locked mode, is impossible.

I'm on my school's Chromebook, so i experienced it.
I hope this helps.

Sorry if my answer/opinion is wrong.